# How to change .less files without restarting the grails application?

Tags: grails, less

I am using the lesscss-resources plugin in my Grails application. Everything is working as expected. But when I make changes in .less files, I need to restart the whole application every time.

Is there a way that Grails recompiles those changes directly?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks, Urs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/lesscss-resources):

> Note that the files to be imported are not part of the resources bundle, so any changes will not trigger a rebuild of the resource.

So, if you're less files that you are modifying, you might be out of luck at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not using less with Grails, but what worked for me was actually deleting my cookies for the domain for which you want the CSS to update.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.